# Where to place CSS for specific screen dimension?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am building a responsive design with bootstrap and I have two navigation bars, one for mobile and one for desktop.

Being a mobile first framework, the desktop one only triggers at `min-width:992px` and otherwise is set as `display:none`. I have a whole bunch of css for the desktop navigation, now I was wondering if it would be best to put it in the min width 992 media query, or just leave it outside of the media query.

What is the best practice?

Also, does media query CSS only get loaded when the media query is triggered? I'm fairly sure that CSS just gets loaded as is, but thought i'd ask.

Comment: Direct CSS styling is loaded as part of the DOM, not conditionally. Media Queries, however, are only loaded as the criteria is met.

Comment: @DevlshOne What if the media query is inline with the global CSS i.e. same file. Presumably, the whole file is loaded but isn't wholly acted upon until the said conditions are met. Right?

Comment: @JackWilliams That's correct. That's why you'll often find media queries in their own external stylesheet.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, so that's actionable advice for @Melbourne2991

Comment: Interesting, so for maximum performance I would ideally have media queries in the global css file, and then within them have an import query? Or would it be better to have an import query and place the media query within its own file?

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use (%) instead of (px)

Comment: Wrostran, Quick tip: Your answer is more appropriate for the commenting section below the question. Thanks.

Comment: It is bootstrap that uses px in media queries, what's wrong with px?